# Laravel - Arrowchat integration issue & cannot access Auth or Session class

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I am facing the arrowchat integration issue with Laravel. Does anyone know how to access the Auth or Session class ? Last time there is a thread talk about this but not working so I try again.

### Orginal statement

```
function get_user_id() 
{ 
    $userid = NULL;
    if (!empty($_SESSION['userid']))
    {
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

    }

    return $userid;
}
```

### Changed statement

```
function get_user_id() 
{    
     $userid = NULL;
     if (Auth::user()) 
     {
        $userid = Auth::user()->id;
     }

     return $userid;
}
```

The changed statement give me a error ( empty page) on debug page so it is not accessing the Auth or Session class of laravel and Arrowchat is in the public folder of Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if user is logged like: Auth::guest(), not Auth::user()
Try this:

```
function get_user_id() 
{    
     if (Auth::guest()){
         return null;
     }
     else {
         return Auth::user()->id;
     }
}
```